# ArgumentError: Factory not registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to run rspec with FactoryGirl, but **I keep getting this error**:

```
1) Products Update with invalid information
     Failure/Error: let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: product
     # ./spec/requests/products_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/products_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

-

Here's **the test with the error** (spec/requests/products_spec.rb):

```
describe "Read" do
    let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product) }
    before { visit product_path(product) }
    it { should have_text(product.title) }
end
```

-

Here's **the factory** (spec/factories.rb):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :product do
        title "Lorem ipsum"
        description "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae ipsum consectetur, semper dolor sed, dignissim enim."
        image_url "lorem.png"
        price 9.95
    end
end
```

-

I **restarted the server** (with Spork and Guard) and nothing changed, though I may not be restarting Spork/Guard correctly.

-

I **do have require 'factory_girl' in my spec/spec_helper.rb.**

-

Here's my **Gemfile**. Note that **I am using "factory_girl_rails"** in my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development do
    gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', require: false
end
```

-

Can you find the error?

Comment: Maybe add `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` to `RSpec.configure` block. But it should work without that in general.

Comment: Also there is no need in spork since `spring` appears, it fully replace it.

Comment: have you tried creating the factory like **spec/factories/products.rb**

Comment: Have you included `require 'spec_helper'` in your spec?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: `require 'spec_helper'` is is in each spec.

Comment: @robzdc: Good thought, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Of note: I asked a friend and he was able to fork my repository and run the tests himself without getting any errors, so I assume my problem is local.  Probably something to do with upgrading to OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I threw a bunch of stuff at this, so it's hard to tell what the precise fix was.  One thing I did was switch `require 'factory_girl'` in spec_helper.rb to `require 'factory_girl_rails'` and that seems to be the most plausible solution.

Also, I added `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` to the `Rspec.configure` block of spec_helper.rb and I think that was also important.

Comment: I had the same error. In my case the problem was that I was using `factory_girl`. The right gem to use with Rails is `factory_girl_rails` (e.g. `gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0', group: [:development, :test]` in your Gemfile.rb).


Adding `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` to the `RSpec.configure` block probably has nothing to do with your problem being solved: the purpose of this line is to allow one to create an object without needing to reference `FactoryGirl` (i.e. `create(:product)` instead of `FactoryGirl.create(:product)`)

Comment: `require factory_bot_rails` instead of just `require factory_bot` in `test_helper` helped me too with rails 5.2.2, ruby 2.5.1 and Minitest instead of RSpec

Answer (score 1):

"ArgumentError: Factory not registered" is also generated if your factory definition is misnamed. Your factory definition might be called `phases.rb`, but the definition should read: `factory :phase do` (singular).